# convert ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT date type to readable format in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

```
Tue, 12 Jul 2016 07:44:24 GMT
```

is the output i am getting in the string . i need to convert this format to the UNIX time stamp but it is not in proper format the format of the given string is.

```
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT
```

i want this date in PHP standard format for the UNIX time stamp conversion.

thank you

Comment: please check this link may be help you http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: nope i have checked it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert it into a UNIX time stamp.

Example:

```
$time = strtotime('Tue, 12 Jul 2016 07:44:24 GMT');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
```

Make sure you also set your default timezone if you haven't done so at server level:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Comment: this is working fine.. thanks a lot brother

Answer (score 0):

Your string `Tue, 12 Jul 2016 07:44:24 GMT` is actually a `RFC 2822 formatted date`. You can input run this string via `strtotime()` or `DateTime`, and then format as you wish.

If you wish to format back to RFC 2822 formated date, use `r` as format character, see [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/596827)</kbd>

Comment: yes this is working too .. thanks :-)